# Jquery.UI.Sortable this.placeholder[0].parentNode is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have connected two lists with Sortable. I have one list that contains available items to move to the real list that contains a list of ordered items. My goal is to take an item from one list and move it to the second. When dropped into position in the new list the update event will fire off a json update to the database.

The issue arises when you drop the item then the:
`$("#sortable2").sortable({items: 'li'}).sortable('toArray')` fires off. I then get the `Error: 'this.placeholder.0' is null or not an object` message.

Now in the receiving list I can still move items to resort them and when the update event fires all is well as long as I did not drop a new item into the list.

I have found and tried to apply the bug fix from http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/6054 where it indicates to replace:

```
this.placeholder[0].parentNode.removeChild(this.placeholder[0]);
```

with

```
if(this.placeholder[0].parentNode)
this.placeholder[0].parentNode.removeChild(this.placeholder[0]);
```

**Additonal details:** I discovered a bit closer that the error is being caused when I get a json error back and I try to `$("#sortable2").sortable('cancel');` I guess now I will need to find out how to do a cancel when I have moved data into the list from another list.

That fix did not work.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Does anyone know how to revert 2 lists back to the original with 'cancel' if there is an error of some sort? The cancel is what is throwing the error.

My code:

```
$(function() {
            $("#sortable2").sortable({
                connectWith: '.connectedSortable'
                ,
                placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight'
                ,
                items: 'li:not(.ui-state-disabled)'
                ,
                receive: function(event, ui) {

                },
                remove: function(event, ui) {

                },
                update: function() {
                    $("#sortable2").sortable("refreshPositions");
                    //updateCycleSort();
                }
            })

            $("#sortable1").sortable({
                connectWith: '.connectedSortable'
                ,
                placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight'
            })

            $("#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li").disableSelection();
        });

        function updateCycleSort() {

            alert($("#sortable2").sortable({items: 'li'}).sortable('toArray'));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: updateCycleSortUrl,
                data: "cycles=" + $("#sortable2").sortable({items: 'li'}).sortable('toArray'),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    if (response.error == "false") {
                        //$('div#resultRecordDetail').html(response.message);
                        //$('div#resultRecordDetail').addClass('success');
                        //autoHide(2500);
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#sortable2").sortable('cancel');
                        alert("error");
                    }
                },
                error: function(response, textStatus, AjaxException) {
                    alert("BIG error " + response.statusText);
                    //$('div.dialog-result').html(response.statusText);
                    //$('div.dialog-result').addClass('error').show();
                    //autoHide(10000);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, and what I found is that the start event has enough information to determine where the item came from (it's possible that beforeStop also has this, but I don't recall now if I tried that, or what I found).  So I just remember the original location until the JSON call returns, and put it back on failure.

Comment: I received this error message when I connected a droppable to a sortable.  The error was because when an element was dropped I would hide the panel that the droppable belonged to.  Making sure the originating container of your droppable/sortable is not altered before it completes any callback seems to be necessary.

Comment: Hey @awcrud ,I am having a similar problem.. is there a work around that? I need to hide the panel and can't get around that...

Answer (score 0):

You can't cancel after stop() has returned.  You'll have to implement your own.

There are still bugs to contend with, such as http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6054